# Physical memory problems on Win7. Physical memory and System Commit memory

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have 16GB of RAM setup. I have enough of this memory, but WINDOWS does not want to use it in full, applications close at 11GB / 16GB. That's bad.

I understand why this happens. WINDOWS focuses on "System Commit" memory, when it finishes WINDOWS goes crazy, and it shouldn’t be like this, I would like WINDOWS to focus on real memory, instead System Commit memory, is it possible to make that?

I also do not want to use SWAP(paging)-file. It should be enough physical memory. I do not have similar problems on other OS.

[image: memory]

Comment: There is no question here, just a rant with bad language.

Comment: Open Task Manager, go the Performance Tab, then click on memory in that tab. What are the In use and Available numbers - should total close to 16 GB

Comment: @Tetsujin It was a question.


John You can see the information in the screenshot that is attached to the question. Here i still have 5GB of available memory, but it will not be used. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/b69JE.png)

Comment: The Windows memory model guarantees that virtual memory will be available to a process once it has committed it. You have badly written programs that are committing memory instead of reserving it.

Comment: There is ***no performance benefit*** to running Windows without a swap file.  Windows is designed to use one (even if you have 1TB ram).  This is the sort of thing that happens when you disable the swap file.  [Here is an article](https://www.howtogeek.com/126430/htg-explains-what-is-the-windows-page-file-and-should-you-disable-it/) on the topic.  There are many more on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the commit limit is too low for the current workload. There are 3 ways to solve this problem.

1. Reduce the workload so the commit limit is adequate.
2. Add RAM to increase the commit limit.
3. Enable an adequate pagefile. I suggest a system managed pagefile. This is the default configuration and what most people use.

For the current workload and configuration you clearly do NOT have enough RAM for your workload. But it likely would be with the simple configuration change suggested. You have 5 GB RAM available. Windows isn't using it because it isn't needed. What is needed is more commit limit and that isn't available.

The commit charge is somewhat difficult to explain. It doesn't help that there are many Internet articles that get it very wrong. But I will try to explain.

When an application or the system needs memory it asks the system memory manager. The commit charge is the total of all such requests. Often an application will ask for more than is currently needed. In many cases the application doesn't know how much memory it will need but wants to be sure it will be available when needed. This isn't as bad as it may seem. A memory block (usually 4096 bytes) that isn't in use doesn't add to RAM usage. Only when a block is used for something is RAM assigned for it.

When the system memory manager agrees to a memory request is makes a promise that there will be some place to store the data. That could be in RAM or the pagefile. The total space available for these request is the commit limit. It is RAM size plus pagefile size minus a small overhead. With no pagefile the commit limit is slightly less than RAM size.

If an application requests memory and it would exceed the commit limit the request is denied. This is what is happening in your case. This can happen even when there is plenty of RAM available. Keeping memory requests within the commit limit ensures that even if all applications use all the memory requested there will be no problems. And applications have every right to do so because the memory manager promised (made the commitment) that it would be available. This probably won't happen but it could.

Note that enabling a large pagefile does not imply that it will be used. To increase the commit limit it just has to be there. Actual usage is usually quite modest.

The explanation given here is very simplified. The reality is much more complicated. There is no provision for the user to change this. This could only be done by Microsoft and the end result would be a less reliable system with little benefit.

By disabling the pagefile you are forcing the memory manager to do things it normally would not do. Enable the pagefile and the memory manager will work as designed. Performance may improve and your problems will go away.